# Problem with saving selected ROIs in an image with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm a noob trying to code something that would allow the user to select specific regions of an image and save each of these as cropped images. I need the user to be able to select two different kinds of features (namely, EdU+ and EdU- cells from microscopy files) and save these. So far, I've addressed this by having cv2.selectROIs() open the same image twice in a row with different instructions. However, I can't figure why no files seem to be saved when I try this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

def select_features(feature, instruction, image_file):
    # Resize image to make it manageable on screen
    img_resized = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(image_file),(800,800))
    
    # Select regions of interest (ROIs)
    ROIs = cv2.selectROIs(instruction, img_resized)
    
    feature_number = 0
    
    for rect in ROIs:
        x1 = rect[0]
        y1 = rect[1]
        x2 = rect[2] 
        y2 = rect[3]
        
        img_crop = img_resized[y1:y1+y2, x1:x1+x2]
        
        cv2.imwrite('D:/test_classification' + feature + image_file[:-4] + 'crop' + str(feature_number) + '.png', img_crop)
    
        feature_number += 1
    
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
image = filedialog.askopenfilename()
select_features('S phase','Select EdU+ cells', image)
select_features('Other','Select EdU- cells', image)
```

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: `image_file` has the whole, absolute path including `C:/` or anything like that, such that your concatenated filename isn't valid. Extract the actual filename from the absolute path, and you're done.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot!

Comment: OK turns out I just add to split image_file so that I get everything after the last '/' in the file path. Thanks again HansHirse!